# Sentence validation

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is the below sentence correct?

"Today is gone good".

People are saying that the day is passed, so we have to use "has" instead of "is".

Also please tell me the correct usage of "good", if it is wrong.

Comment: Please ask this on the sister site http://ell.stackexchange.com/, which deals with basic English questions.

Comment: "Today has gone well."

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)  Shouldn't we use "gone good"?.kindly explain with reason.

Comment: Maybe he means "Today is gone for good."

Comment: It's true that you need a perfect here, but actually "is gone" may be a perfect in slightly old-fashioned English, since "go" is a verb of motion.

Answer (score 1):

You use "has gone" rather than "is gone" since your "point of view" is retrospective -- you're looking back at the past, so a past tense form of the verb is needed.  ("Today went well" would work too, but "has gone well" has a more musical flavor to it, and would often be preferred. Plus I'm sure there's some convoluted technical reason why it's preferred.)

"Well" is primarily an adverb.  "Good" primarily an adjective.  Though both can "legally" be used in opposite roles it's more idiomatic to use "well" for adverbial uses.  "Well" modifies the verb "has gone" and hence is used as an adverb, and is the preferred choice.